Acceptance of Turing Machines is NP-Hard?
I had a question in my exam 'Show that the acceptance of turing machines is NP-Hard'. How do I go about this question?

Consider any language $L\in NP$. By definition, it has a non-determinstic TM $M$.
Could you claim that:
$x\in L \longleftrightarrow M$ accepts $(M,x) $?
If this claim is correct, what does this imply on the relation between $L$ and $Acc$?
A reduction $L\leq ACC$ holds for any $L\in NP$. What does this imply on $ACC$?

I interpreted "acceptance of TMs" to mean "acceptance of deterministic TMs". I think a little more work is needed here if that is the case.
